# Error when trying to read 4 txt files into 1 dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parse-error

I have four .txt files which I want to directly read into 1 dataframe with pandas. I found in another public question the following code:

```
path = r'C:\Users\xx\map1' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, delimiter=';')
    li.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 21 fields in line 443, saw 22

I googled this error and found out that some other people experienced the same, and apperantly often caused by the delimeter. I therefore added "del=;" to the code, but that did not help either. I also read that sometimes it is caused due to different number of columns in the files, but that is not the case in my files. All four files also have the same columns.. So not really sure how to solve this.

Comment: Look at the affected TXT file, line 443 and analyze it. What makes you so sure that it isn't 22 columns? Can you post that line? If not, isolate that line into a single file, read it with Python and have each column be printed on an extra line. That way you'll see where you and Python differ in opinions.

Comment: the answer is here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html  , but also make sure that the dataframes are mergable.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help! I see indeed that on line 443 something went wrong. The value of 1 column contained the following: "PXR; 150 mL", which is thus misinterpreted as a column delimiter.. Any chance that you know how to solve this aswell?

Answer (score 0):

If you have same columns in all your csv files then you can try the code below. I have added header=0 so that after reading txt first row can be assigned as the column names.

```
import pandas as pd

import glob

path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files' # use your path

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")

li = []

for filename in all_files:

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, sep=" ", header=0)

    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

An alternative to above

```
path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files'                     # use your path

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))     # advisable to use os.path.join as this makes concatenation OS independent

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files)

concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)

# doesn't create a list, nor does it append to one
```

or you can use one liner

```
import glob

import os

import pandas as pd  

df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "my_files*.txt"))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Gaston. Unfortunately none of the codes did work. The first one returns the following: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 3, saw 8 
The second code: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 4400, saw 3. But it looks like that your code does not use " ; " as a delimter right?

Comment: So my probelm is actualy that I have a delimter conflict. In one of my lines a value also contains a delimiter, which causes that for that line 1 extra column is created. I am trying to figure out how to solve this, but with no luck yet.